# Exposing composite component attribute to children

Tags: jsf-2, attributes, myfaces, composite-component

I have the necessity to load some data in a dataTable using lazy loading. Unfortunatelly, primefaces dataTable only suports lazy loading with pagination, but this is unacceptable to this project, so I created and tested some mechanisms to permit lazy loading in datatable using scroll (primefaces's liveScroll isn't lazy loading). Now I need to move these mechanisms to a composite component, so I decided to wrap primefaces dataTable:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="var" required="true" targets="tabela"/>
    <c:attribute name="value" required="true" targets="tabela" type="java.util.List"/>
    <c:attribute name="scrollable" targets="tabela"/>
    <c:attribute name="liveScroll" required="false" default="false"/>
    <c:attribute name="height" targets="tabela"/>
    <c:attribute name="emptyMessage" targets="tabela" default="Nenhuma dado a ser exibido"/>
    <c:attribute name="rows" targets="tabela"/>
    <c:attribute name="action" method-signature="void method()" required="false"/>

</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <p:dataTable id="tabela" var="#{cc.attrs.var}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                     scrollable="#{scrollable}" height="#{cc.attrs.height}"
                     emptyMessage="#{cc.attrs.emptyMessage}" rows="10">
            <c:insertChildren/>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:remoteCommand name="comandoAtualizarTabela" action="#{cc.attrs.action}" update="tabela" process="@none"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if ("#{cc.attrs.liveScroll}") {
                var idEscapadoPainelLista = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("#{cc.clientId}");
                jQuery(idEscapadoPainelLista).find(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").scroll(function () {
                    if ((this.scrollTop == this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight))
                        comandoAtualizarTabela();
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</c:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

When I try to use this component, no data is showed in the rows cause of this exception:

```
[#|2012-07-12T09:34:10.010-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-10;|org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwarePropertyNotFoundException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getType(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:79)
at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputTextRenderer.java:113)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:647)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:583)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:273)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1317)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.process(UIData.java:1919)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.processColumnChildren(UIData.java:1904)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:1761)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1317)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1317)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:209)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1324)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._processValidatorsDefault(UIViewRoot.java:1350)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.access$500(UIViewRoot.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ProcessValidatorPhaseProcessor.process(UIViewRoot.java:1443)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1306)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:793)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsExecutor.execute(ProcessValidationsExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at fr.xebia.servlet.filter.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.gr|#]
[#|2012-07-12T09:34:10.011-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-10;|izzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:131)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:76)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:195)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getType(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:75)
... 90 more|#]
```

**ADDED**

The application uses spring version 3.0.7. Once the application have more than 20 spring xml files, I'm showing just part of one spring file... This part configures the dialog I'm testing with the composite component:

```
<bean id="controladorPopupCadastroUnidade" class="com.hrgi.web.cadastro.controladores.popups.ControladorPopupCadastroUnidade" scope="request">
     <property name="controladorArmazenamento" ref="controladorArmazenamentoUnidade"/>
    <property name="conversorValor" ref="conversorUnidade"/>
    <property name="modelo" ref="modeloPopupCadastroUnidade"/>
    <property name="popupAlerta" ref="controladorPopupAlerta"/>
    <property name="recuperadorValores" ref="unidadeDao"/>
    <property name="popupConfirmacao" ref="controladorPopupConfirmacao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="modeloPopupCadastroUnidade" class="com.hrgi.web.ui.modelos.ModeloPopupCRUD" scope="session">
    <property name="visivel" value="false"/>
    <property name="mensagemSucesso" value="${gerais.lista.sucesso}" />
</bean>

<bean id="controladorArmazenamentoUnidade" class="com.hrgi.persistencia.controladores.ControladorArmazenamento" scope="request">
    <property name="armazenador" ref="unidadeDao"/>
    <property name="atualizador" ref="unidadeDao"/>
    <property name="removedor" ref="unidadeDao"/>
    <property name="conversor" ref="conversorUnidade"/>
</bean>
```

to help you see the problem, here is the dataTable part of xhtml file I'm trying use teh cc:

```
<h:panelGroup id="painelLista" layout="block" styleClass="clearfix">
    <hrgi:dataTable var="bean" value="#{modeloPopupCadastroUnidade.lista}"
                         scrollable="true" height="145"
                         action="#{controladorPopupCadastroUnidade.atualizarValores}"
                         liveScroll="true" rows="10">
        <p:column headerText="Nome" style="width: 23%">
            <hrgi:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="saida">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bean.descricao}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="entrada">
                    <p:inputText value="#{bean.descricao}" maxlength="35" style="width: 90%"/>
                </f:facet>
            </hrgi:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Sigla">
            <hrgi:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="saida">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bean.sigla}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="entrada">
                    <p:inputText value="#{bean.sigla}" maxlength="5"/>
                </f:facet>
            </hrgi:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Fator" sortBy="#{bean.fator}">
            <hrgi:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="saida">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bean.fator}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="entrada">
                    <hrgi:spinner value="#{bean.fator}" dinheiro="false" fator="1" local="pt-BR" width="40"/>
                </f:facet>
            </hrgi:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Fracionado" sortBy="#{bean.fracionado}">
            <hrgi:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="saida">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bean.fracionado eq true?'Sim':'Não'}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="entrada">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.fracionado}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </hrgi:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Unitário" sortBy="#{bean.unitario}">
            <hrgi:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="saida">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bean.unitario eq true?'Sim':'Não'}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="entrada">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.unitario}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </hrgi:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <hrgi:rowEditor action="#{controladorPopupCadastroUnidade.editarValor(bean)}" update="alerta" indice="#{bean.indice}"/>
            <p:commandLink title="#{msgGerais['gerais.excluir']}"                               action="#{controladorPopupCadastroUnidade.removerValor(bean)}"                                       update="painelLista alerta confirmacao" immediate="true">
                <h:graphicImage library="img" name="remover.png"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </hrgi:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Probably the problem is that var property can't be used outside composite component... Is there a way I can expose this attribute externally? How can I solve it?

Comment: @Ravi I'm not using CDI, I'm using spring 3.0.7, and the injection is totally made with xml files...

Comment: @Ravi added xhtm file with use of component and the part of spring file that declares the beans used by this xhtml.

Comment: I'm not using Spring DM. The first question I didn't understand (is there other way to deploy??)

Comment: Nevermind, I just wanted to know if you were using Spring DM